# changing directory whist running python code

Tags: python

I have a piece of code which runs four other pieces of code. However when those codes run they write their out put writes to the directory I run this code in. I was wondering if there is a way to run the code so it changes directory after every time, here is my code:

```
loop=np.arange(187761,187854)
for ext in loop:
 ext=str(ext)
 s0='' 
 dcom=["rm *.txt"]
 dcom=s0.join(dcom)
 nes=os.system(dcom)

 a=sys.argv[1]
 com=['cd /cygdrive/e/desar2.cosmology.illinois.edu+7443/DESFiles/desardata/OPS/red/', a,'/red/DECam_00',ext, '/']
 com=s0.join(com)
 print com
 sres=os.system(com)

 com=['python /home/pythoncodes/other4.py ', '00'+ext]
 com=s0.join(com)
 print com
 sres=os.system(com)

 com=['python /home/pythoncodes/correctedmo.py ', '00'+ext]
 com=s0.join(com)
 print com
 sres=os.system(com)

 com=['python /home/pythoncodes/graphs.py ', '00'+ext]
 com=s0.join(com)
 print com
 sres=os.system(com)

 com=['python /home/pythoncodes/whiskerother4.py ', '00'+ext]
 com=s0.join(com)
 print com
 sres=os.system(com)
```

I was hoping the top part would change the directory for every ext, but it doesn't. Is there a way to do this or should I just alter the programs to write to different directories?

Comment: Don't use `os.system`. Use the `subprocess` module instead. It lets you set the working directory *per command*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.chdir(path)` to change the current directory.

Comment: You should accept the answer if you think it's Ok.

Comment: I have to wait until ten mins after you've answered it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python so no code in this answer. What I understand is that if you run the script under directory `/foo/`, the script outputs to `/foo/bar.txt`. If you change the directory to `faa`, you'll output to `/faa/bar.txt`. Next, you want a way of always writing to a *specific* directory no matter what dir the script was executed in.

You *can* change the directory your code works in but that's probably not what you want to do. You need to output your file to the target directory in one pass, eg. `write("~/static_dir/"+file_name, file_contents)`.

The reason is very simple:

- Fewer commands
- Harder to get lost in directories